# How to refactor inner class MouseAdapter?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, encapsulation

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
public class Foo extends JPanel
{
    private int m;
    private int n;
    private int o;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(new Bar());
    }

    class Bar extends MouseAdapter
    {
        // ...
        // methods here access and modify values of the private
        // instance variables.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Obviously I can add simple accessors and mutators to `Foo` but that gets tedious fast and completely breaks encapsulation. How can I refactor this inner class while keeping damage to encapsulation to a minimum?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use an inner class instead of an anonymous one?

Comment: Yes. The inner and outer classes are quite big (both over 200+ lines of code each), and I need to reduce the size of this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these classes seem too big, then you should split them.  The first step in splitting them would be to stop relying on private instance variables of the outer class.  You could, as you say, add public getters and setters, but better would be to have Foo implement a public interface of Bar, and have Bar simply talk to that interface.  And initialize each Bar with self.

```
public class Bar extends MouseAdapter {
    public interface Caller {
        void thingClicked();
        ...
    }
}

public class Foo extends JPanel implements Bar.Caller {
    ...
}
```

So where now in Bar you have something like:

```
public void mouseUp() {
   m = m + 1;
   n = 0
}
```

you would now have

```
public void mouseUp() {
   caller.thingClicked();
}
```

and, in Foo:

```
public void thingClicked() {
   m = m + 1;
   n = 0
}
```

It's hard to make this clear without more specifics, but basically your outer class is responding to messages, and the mouse listener is only responsible for delivering those messages, not for what happens in response to them.  In the examples above it looks like this is more code than what you already have, but I suspect you'll find that slicing it out in this way ultimately leads to less code - and certainly code which is easier to test and reuse.

Comment: "but better would be to have Foo implement a public interface of Bar" does this mean that Foo and Bar both implement the same interface of some sort?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the declaration of Bar.Caller; does this answer your question?

Comment: Yup, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to put the class `bar` in a new file and inject everything you need there into the constructor. You'd need to change your primitive types like `int` into objects like `Integer`. Then you can create a Builder class that steers the construction of `Foo` and `Bar`. Let's assume for simplicity you need the same instance of `Baz` in all of your `Foo` and `Bar` instances:

```
class Builder {
  // objects that both classes need are stored as member variables
  // if you need multiple instances of baz you can also store a BazBuilder here
  private Baz baz;

  public Builder(Baz baz) {
    this.baz=baz;
  }

  public Foo buildFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(baz);
    return foo;
  }

  public Bar buildBar() {
    Bar bar = new Bar(baz);
    return bar;
  }
}
```

This is only a minimalistic example but it's easy to extend. `Builder#buildFoo()` could take arguments that are needed in the constructor of `Foo` and likewise for `Bar`.

**EDIT**
Small example of what it might look like with a `BazBuilder`:

```
class BazBuilder {

 Baz build(int value) {
   return new Baz(value);
 }
}
```

And in `Builder` you can use it like so:

```
class Builder {
  private BazBuilder bazBuilder;

  public Build(BazBuilder bazBuilder) {
    this.bazBuilder = bazBuilder;
  }

  public Foo buildFoo() {
    Baz baz = bazBuilder.build(5);
    Bar bar = new Bar(baz);
    Foo foo = new Foo(baz);
    foo.add(bar);
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to change all of my primitive types to wrapper objects?

Comment: @JohnH It really depends on what you want to achieve. If you use primitive types the two values will be independant. So if you change a value in one class the value in the other class stays the same. What I usually do is make a custom wrapper, read the values in one class and manipulate them in another one. This will not work with primitives.

Comment: True. Is there a particular name for this design pattern?

Comment: @JohnH It's 2 patterns actually. One is Dependency Injection which means the constructor of a class gets all the objects instead of creating them on his own. The second pattern is builder pattern which is used to make the object creation independent from object logic. As for the custom wrapper where you read in one class and manipulate in the other. If that has a particular name I don't know it.